# Moving cursor to the middle of the line where it currently is

Tags: spacemacs, evil, functions, cursor, motion

Is there a way to define a function that, when called, would move the cursor to the middle (or close to the middle) of the current line, similarly to how we can move it to the beginning and end of the line?

I frequently find myself having to do <kbd>C-left</kbd> or <kbd>C-right</kbd> multiple times to reach a word that is more to the middle of the line.  I guess that if it were possible to have a function, bounded to a shortcut combination, to allow me to quickly jump close to the middle of the line, then navigation would become quite more efficient to me.

Comment: You might want to try out `avy` (https://github.com/abo-abo/avy) or one of the similar packages that lets you jump to a specific visible location. For example, `avy-goto-char-in-line` prompts for a character and then provides keys to jump to all the instances of that character in the current line. (It makes more sense when you see a demo or try it out!)

Comment: [Binary line navigation](https://github.com/mgrachten/bln-mode) might be what you're looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following function moves the cursor to the middle of the current line:

```
(defun my/move-to-middle ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((begin (line-beginning-position))
         (end (line-end-position))
         (middle (/ (+ end begin) 2)))
    (goto-char middle)))
```

You can bind this to a key (I used <kbd>C-c m</kbd>) using

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m") 'my/move-to-middle)
```

Note that this calculates the middle of the line using `line-beginning-position` and `line-end-position`, which also count whitespace at the beginning and end of the line. This means that for indented text/code, the calculated middle will be slightly to the left of the middle of the text, and slightly to the right for lines with lots of whitespace at the end of the line.

**Edit:** Just found out `evil-mode` has this functionality already. You can move the cursor to the middle of the current line using <kbd>g m</kbd>, which calls `evil-middle-of-visual-line`. This moves the cursor to the middle column in the window, instead of the middle character in the line. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25137407/4089396).

Comment: Thanks for your defined function and for calling my attention for the evil's keybinding. Although I will be using evil's, your function will allow me to do some further customizations (e.g. jumping to the middle of another line informed by number).

Answer (score 3):

While this doesn't directly answer your question (I think Amot already covered that part just fine), I'll just point out that many Emacs users solve these kinds of problems by navigating with <kbd>C-s</kbd>, i.e. rather than think "move close to middle of line", they think "move to the part of the buffer with this text".

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move the curor vertically to middle of the window you can use
`evil-window-middle`. In spacemacs you only need press key "M", and btw, "H" for top, "L" for bottom.